# Java library for get letter synonym / similar glyph

Tags: java, unicode, glyph

I would like to know whether there is a library which allows characters to get their synonyms?

something like:

```
char c = getNextChar();
if (c == latin.H || c == cyrillic.H) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, such a library does not exist... and I don't think one to one character mapping between languages could be done!! Try to fetch unicode in your getNextChar call line.. that way you will be able to map the code to the language char it designates..

Answer (score 2):

So, as I understand it, you don't want “synonyms” of letters; you want letters with the same “glyphs” (shapes).

I don't know if such a library exists. However, you can do it by rendering chars using your favourite font and checking glyph “sameness”.

For example, you can take the following steps:

- Download [UniFont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html), preferrably in its [BDF form](http://unifoundry.com/unifont-5.1.20080820.bdf.gz)
- Calculate a checksum (e.g MD5) for the bitmap of every character
- Group characters based on their checksum.

I created a [small Python 2.7 test script](http://bpaste.net/show/20364/) (for development speed purposes) doing the above steps, producing something like (excerpt):

```
Group 0041
        U+0041 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
        U+0391 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ALPHA
        U+13AA CHEROKEE LETTER GO
Group 0042
        U+0042 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B
        U+0392 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER BETA
        U+0412 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER VE
        U+13F4 CHEROKEE LETTER YV
```

YMMV.